# Adding a CSS subclass to a CSS item used in javascript?

Tags: html, css, subclass

First time using CSS so my question may not make sense. I am using a menu template that uses javascript to slide CSS items around. I have multiple items next to each other and I wanted to alternate the background by making a subclass for the item(eg: `.cc_item .odd{background:#fff}`).

style:

```
.cc_item{
    text-align: center;
    width: 140px;
    height: 600px;
    float: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    background: #e8c486 url(../images/menuBack.jpg) repeat top left;
    position: relative;
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px -3px 10px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px -3px 10px #000;
    box-shadow: 3px -3px 10px #000;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="cc_item" style="z-index:6;">
    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="image" />
    <span class="cc_title">Pizza</span>
    <div class="cc_submenu">
        <ul>
            <li class="cc_content_1">Pizzas</li>
            <li class="cc_content_2">Calzones</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add a `.odd{ }` to the cc_item so in the html I can specify the "odd" cc_item class. I've tried a couple things, but can't seem to get it to work.

1. I don't know the proper way to add a subclass to a css item. I've done it with my table stylesheet, but the "." in front of the cc_item is throwing me off(sorry...really new).
2. I don't know where to specify the "class=odd" in the html.
3. I don't know if I make these changes the javascript that uses `cc_item` will be affected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give an element multiple classes like so:

```
 <div class="cc_item odd" style="z-index:6;">
```

Just separate them by spaces.

To refer to that code using CSS or jQuery, you can chain classes together and refer to them like so:

```
.cc_item.odd { /*styles go here*/ } or $('.cc_item.odd')
```

That will hit anything with both classes. And if you want this to work in IE6, read the instructions here:
http://www.oppenheim.com.au/2009/05/24/multiple-css-classes-a-little-known-ie6-hack/

Also, just an FYI - when you use jQuery's `addClass()` method it will automatically add the space between the classes for you, so all you need to pass through is the odd class.

Comment: Hey! I like this! I did not know you could put two classes in CSS!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any such thing as a CSS subclass.. but try this

Add a new `.cc_item_odd{...}` AFTER your existing Close Brace `}` (I would not just call it `.odd` because that is less descriptive and more conflict prone since there are no subclasses)

When you change your class set `class="cc_item cc_item_odd"` That is how you apply more than one class. I am not sure how your JavaScript is doing the lookup, but I think it will be unaffected